# Under what circumstances is $\ddot{x}=\dot{x}\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, physics, classical-mechanics

I was told a trick by my professors for certain integrals.

Given that the path of a particle in 1D is $x(t)$, then the following is true

$$
\ddot{x}=\frac{d\dot{x}}{dt}=\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}=\dot{x}\frac{d\dot{x}}{dx}
$$

My impression is that this is true for any path, so long as $x$ only depends on $t$.

The reason I ask is for a specific problem in Thornton and Marion. I think the answers I am finding online might be wrong.

Specifically this is 2-1; suppose a force is acting on a single particle. If the force has the form $F=F(x_i,t)=f(x_i)g(t)$, determine if the equation of motion is integrable.

The standard answer I am finding copied and pasted is:

$$
m\ddot{x}_i=f(x_i)g(t)\\
\text{Since it is the case that } \ddot{x}_i = \frac{d\dot{x}}{dt} \text{, then we have}\\
m\frac{d\dot{x}}{f(x_i)}=g(t)dt
$$

Which is then just declared not integrable without further clarification.

Suppose that the substitution for $\ddot{x}$ I mentioned is generally true for functions of one variable.Then we can rewrite the EOM as

$$
m\ddot{x}_i=f(x_i)g(t)\\
m\dot{x}\frac{d\dot{x}_i}{dx_i}=f(x_i)g(t)\\
\text{Which can be rewritten as } m\dot{x}d\dot{x}=f(x_i)g(t)dx_i
$$

To which I would argue that as long as $g(t)$ is not dependent on $x_i$, then the above should be perfectly integrable. Specifically:

$$
\frac{m}{2}\dot{x}^2=g(t)\int f(x_i)dx_i\\
\text{which can be modified to give }\\ \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\dot{x}=\sqrt{g(t)}\sqrt{\int f(x_i)dx_i}\\
\text{which just simply gives } \frac{dx_i}{\sqrt{\int f(x_i)dx_i}}=\sqrt{\frac{2g(t)}{m}}dt
$$

Which would appear to still be integrable.

So have people been copying the wrong solution for years, or am I wrong for some reason I do not see?

Comment: I don't know what $\frac{d\dot x}{dx}$ means here.

Comment: The derivative of the velocity with respect to position in simple terms.

Comment: You would need some assumptions about $x(t)$ in order to justify that meaning.  In effect $x(t)$ would need to be injective (invertible) to justify that velocity is well-defined as a function of position.

Comment: What does it mean for some to NOT be a well defined function?

Comment: In order for $\dot x$ to have a derivative with respect to $x$, it would have to be a function of $x$.  But if the same position $x$ corresponds to different velocities at different times, then $\dot x$ is *not* a well-defined function of $x$ (because the velocity will depend not only on $x$ but on the choice of time $t$ at which that location is reached).

Comment: Which would generally be the case moving under the influence of a conservative force, iirc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to think about this trick. One takes the original autonomous equation $m\ddot x=f(x)$, multiplies it with $\dot x$ and integrates using the chain rule to get $\frac{m}2\dot x^2=F(x)$, where $F'=f$.

The other point-of-view is that the independent variable gets changed from $t$ to $x$. This demands that the solution under consideration is monotonous, at least in some segment around the initial point. To avoid symbolic confusion, declare a function with a new letter, $\dot x=u(x)$. Then $\ddot x=u'(x)\dot x=u'(x)u(x)$.

In your case, the substitution of the independent variable would also make $t$ a function of $x$, so that the equation becomes
$$
mu'(x)u(x)=f(x)g(t(x))
$$
Due to the unknown function $t(x)$, this is not directly integrable or separable.

Comment: Would my method not result in an implicit definition of x(t)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean monotonic?

Comment: If you replace $t$ with $x$, you need, at least locally, a bijection. For a continuous function this is equivalent to $x(t)$ being (strongly) monotonous. Or in other words, you want to avoid points where $\dot x(t)=0$.

Comment: Or rather the points where dot_x(t)=0 define the boundary between different solutions to the same original differential equation?

Comment: No, different segments of the same solution. For instance starting with $\ddot x+x=0$ this leads to $\dot x=\pm\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$ where $\dot x=0$ separates the swings in alternating directions.