# How does substituting $ u = y' $ in $ y''(t) - y'(t) = y(t) y'(t) $ reduce it to $ uu' − u = yu $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, substitution

I am trying to understand a substitution step at [http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/~jiao/teaching/ams501_fall11/notes/hiorder_nonlinear.pdf](http://www.ams.sunysb.edu/%7Ejiao/teaching/ams501_fall11/notes/hiorder_nonlinear.pdf) (page 2).

Here is the step I am unable to understand:

> ... we obtain $$ y''(t) - y'(t) = y(t) y'(t). $$ This is an automanous equation. The substitution $ u = y' $ reduces the order to first-order equation $$ uu' − u = yu. $$

Shouldn't the substitution $ u(t) = y'(t) $ reduce $$ y''(t) - y'(t) = y(t) y'(t) $$ to $$ u'(t) - u(t) = y(t) u(t), $$ that is $$ u' - u = yu?$$

Comment: It's not $u(t)=y'(t)$. If that were the case, you would be right. But it is $u(y)=y(t)$; and your link explains clearly how to evaluate $y''(t)$ in that case.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4227031/under-what-circumstances-is-ddotx-dotx-fracd-dotxd, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3065331/showing-ddotx-frac-mathrmd-mathrmdx-frac12-dotx2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the first page of the notes:
$$
y''(x) = \frac{du}{dx}=\frac{du}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=u'(y)u(y)\tag{1}
$$

The substitution used is $u(y)=y'(x)$. In your example on page 2, replace $x$ with $t$ in (1).

Answer (score 1):

It's $u'=\dfrac {du}{dy}$. You can also integrate without substitution:
$$y''(t) - y'(t) = y(t) y'(t)$$
$$y''(t) - y'(t) = \dfrac 12 (y^2(t))'$$
Integrate:
$$y'-y=\dfrac { y^2}2+C_1$$
This DE is separable.